# TV antenna far from box - how to ground?

Tags: grounding, tv-antenna

Following under the eaves of the house it is about 70 feet to the box. This seems a long way for a good ground connection. A shortcut through the attic is possible but the room closest to the box has a vaulted ceiling with no attic above it.

There is a much closer location that was where the house's original box was. Any likelihood that the defunct box (now full of  nest of wires) has a proper connection to ground?

Another option might be a cold water spigot that is quite close to the antenna.

EDIT
I can change to location of the antenna to the analogous spot on the opposite side of the house. It will be a 40 ft straight shot to the spot (below) where the cable box ground is.

Adding two pic of connections to water pipe.

Primary connection
[image]

nearby second connection of gnd for cable box
[image]
What is in the spot of the original box
[image]

The new box environment
[image]

Comment: Do you have an intersystem bonding termination at your new panel location?  How was the grounding electrode conductor rerun to reach the new panel when the service upgrade was performed?

Comment: I do not see anything eternal to the box. I edited the question to include photos. The shiny conduit on the left brings 240 to a hot tub. The upgrade was performed by the previous owner. When the ceiling behind the box was vaulted (on my watch) it took a lot of electrician time.

Comment: Who do you have for an electric utility, and can you find where your ground rods and/or water pipe bond connection are? Also, are your water service and indoor plumbing plastic or metal?

Comment: We have SCE and have metal plumbing. I'm starting to think I need an electrician.

Comment: Can you find where the electrical system is bonded to the water pipes at, then? (There should be a clamp on your plumbing somewhere with a bare copper wire going off it that goes off to your panel.)

Comment: I found a place that looks like two cables clamp onto a water pipe. I is on the same side of the house as the box but 15' away. Nearby is a ground from a cable box mounted on the outside of the house going to a water pipe.

Comment: The good news is that that Stab-Lock box is no longer in service except as a junction box/part of the conduit system.

Comment: Shouldn't your TV antenna be grounded to the earth only, so if lightning strikes it the high voltage goes to ground and not your house systems ?

Comment: @AlaskaMan -- the NEC requires the TV antenna ground be bonded to the mains grounding system so that your breakers (or the utility's!) can clear a power cross to the TV antenna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I would mount the antenna on the same side of the house as the current box, and run straight-shot to the cold water bond point

Given that you can't rely on the integrity of metal plumbing to bond things together, your best bet is to place the antenna so that you can run the antenna ground wire as a straight shot to the existing water pipe bond point. This will give you a decent place to tie into the grounding electrode system at, provided you clean up the paint and such so that a good connection can be made with a split-bolt or other listed connector; with a bit of work, you could even retrofit an Intersystem Bonding Termination device there.